# Ionic 2 Yelp API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, yelp

I'm trying to connect an Ionic 2 app to Yelp's API. Right now I'm just using a blank Ionic 2 application generated from the CLI and running on my localhost.

My code:

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`home.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  restaurants:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer someString');
    var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    this.http.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=deli20&latitude=39.59754&longitude=-104.872934', options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.restaurants = data.data.children;
        console.log(this.restaurants);
    });
  }



}
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>
  <!--Just using Ionic 2's default home page, just wanna output my JSON to the console for now.-->
</ion-content>
```

The page renders correctly, but the error I get in the console: "Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful"

The response looks like this:

```
{"error": {"code": "TOKEN_MISSING", "description": "An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint."}}
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Looks like you need to supply an access token in the HTTP Header - look here for more: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/45

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing with:     
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer someString');
    var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

Comment: You're replacing "someString" with your actual token, right?

Comment: Haha, yes, I am. 

I did notice this Github issue where the writer determined that the Yelp API does not support CORS or JSONP. https://github.com/ryanchristo/fcc-nightlife-app/issues/2

Would this mean an Ionic 2 app would not be able to access the Yelp API, since (I'm pretty sure) it makes the request with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Add this [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) to your browser, turn it on and reload the page. It should work fine

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).